# Strategy Pattern using unique pointers in C++ using a for loop

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I'm new to the concept of C++ and pointers so I would appreciate some feedback here!

Currently, I have this code where x has a virtual function `someFunction()` that all the derived class implements:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base_Class> x = std::unique_ptr<Base_Class>(nullptr);

for (int i = 0; i < someIteration; i++) {
    if (condition1) {
        x = std::unique_ptr<Derived_Class1>(Derived_Class1());
    } 

    else if (condition2) {
        x = std::unique_ptr<Derived_Class2>(Derived_Class2());
    }

    // and so on ...
    else {
        x = std::unique_ptr<Derived_ClassX>(Derived_ClassX());
    }
    
    x->someFunction(); // Which calls the derived class's function
}
```

** Edited my question after some reading up **

So after some reading up, I realize my code is similar to the Strategy Pattern (which was essentially what I was trying to achieve rather that using dynamic polymorphism on my object itself, which would eliminate my conditions itself as one of the comments mentioned), just that I do not have a `setStrategy` method, and I go onto directly create the unique pointers directly and apply the strategy that I want.

I'll focus on the main question:

At the end of the loop, does the pointer of the derived_class gets deleted automatically (since we are using smart pointers), and hence x becomes a nullptr? And then it gets re-assigned (not sure if this is the correct word) to another pointer again in the loop?

Comment: You should not create an object just to dynamically switch what function is called. Rather, you should create an object for a period of time during which you'll call a bunch of function transparently on them. What are your actual `Derived_Class1` here ? It would help answering if we knew what they are and their logical lifetimes

Comment: The most obvious problem I see with your code, is that by testing a condition just to decide what function gets called, you are negating the entire reason for dynamic, inheritance based polymorphism. The point of this kind of polymorphism is you don't have to test before calling, you just call and the object does the right thing according to its type, not according to some external test.

Comment: Questions are free on StackOverflow - if you have 4 questions, then ask 4 separate questions. That way, we can see which of those are already answered, and which still need an answer. And it looks like some of your questions might already be answered - check the search. When you write the question, StackOverflow will try to see if there's already an answer, but that doesn't work well when you stuff 4 questions in one.

Comment: The current situation I have is:
The conditions represent different states, so I'm like changing between between different "solvers" depending on the state I receive and then calling the `solve()` function which is virtual and inherited by the derived classes, kind of like the strategy pattern but I thought dynamic polymorphism would be applicable as it made sense to me (to switch between solvers and call the derived methods). Does that mean dynamic polymorphism isn't even applicable this way?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but after some reading up, isn't my code here the "Strategy Pattern" without any `setStrategy()` method? I just go straight to creating a new pointer to the strategy that I need.

Comment: `x = std::unique_ptr<Derived_Class1>(Derived_Class1());` is wrong for more than one reason. It will not compile. Perhaps you want `std::unique_ptr<Base_Class> x = nullptr; /* note no  unique_ptr<Base_Class> */ ... x = std::make_unique<Derived_Class1>()`. Or perhaps you want `BaseClass* x; ... x = &myDerivedClass1Object;` (yes a dumb pointer) where `myDerivedClass1Object` is some kind of a global object. If you use a smart pointer, the old object will get deleted upon re-assignment and not at the end of the loop, but the result is much the same.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with doing something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < someIteration; i++) {
    if (condition1) {
        function1();
    } 

    else if (condition2) {
        function2();
    }

    // and so on ...
    else {
        default_function();
    }
}
```

Comment: I could do this way, but all of the derived classes are clearly subclasses of the base class, so I thought I would try to use dynamic polymorphism to build a solution

Comment: There's no point in using dynamic polymorphism here, since you just immediately call one method on the class, then immediately delete the instance you just created.